# angular 2 looping child component get value as content

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am trying to loop child component in parent component for Angular 2 like below,

```
<segment-header>
</segment-header>
<segment-content *ngFor="let content of listContent">
</segment-content>
```

where listContent is json array. Hence content is json object,
And the same content should be look like this.

```
<div class="segment-content-class">
    {{content.code}} = {{content.value}}
</div>
```

My issue is if I loop inside child content it is working fine but if I loop in parent and try to get content object and display it in child it is not working.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to do when you say "if i loop inside child content it is working fine, but if i loop in parent and try to get content object it doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using content-projection in angular2 to achieve this as below,

**AppComponent**

```
<div>
      <segment-header></segment-header>
      <segment-content *ngFor="let content of listContent">
        <div class="segment-content-body"> 
         {{content.code}} = {{content.value}}
        </div>
      </segment-content>
</div>
```

**SegmentHeaderComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'segment-header',
  template: `
    <div> Header </div>
  `,
})
export class SegmentHeaderComponent {}
```

**SegmentContainerComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'segment-content',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content select=".segment-content-body"> </ng-content>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class SegmentContentComponent {}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GawmaVLeuLROhJxD9UZr?p=preview)**